# Help identify a fixed witdth font

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I am interested by the font and haven't seem any fonts similar. http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont gave me some weird clues that didn't help. Can someone help identify the font?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fond it. It's [Fantasque Sans Mono](https://github.com/belluzj/fantasque-sans).